# Pandas alternative to apply - to create new column based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, apply

I have a Pandas dataframe and I would like to add a new column based on the values of the other columns. A minimal example illustrating my usecase is below.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,5,19],[1,2,0],[2,5,9],[8,2,5]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df

    a   b   c
---------------
0   4   5   19
1   1   2   0
2   2   5   9
3   8   2   5

x = df.sample(n=2)
x

    a   b   c
---------------
3   8   2   5
1   1   2   0

def get_new(row):
    a, b, c = row
    return random.choice(df[(df['a'] != a) & (df['b'] == b) & (df['c'] != c)]['c'].values)

y = x.apply(lambda row: get_new(row), axis=1)
x['new'] = y
x

    a   b   c   new
--------------------
3   8   2   5   0
1   1   2   0   5
```

Note: The original dataframe has ~4 million rows and ~6 columns. The number of rows in the sample might vary between 50 and 500. I am running on a 64-bit machine with 8 GB RAM.

The above works, except that it is quite slow (takes about 15 seconds for me). I also tried using `x.itertuples()` instead of `apply` and there is not much of an improvement in this case.

1. It seems that apply(with axis=1) is slow since it does not make use of the vectorized operations. Is there some way I could achieve this in a faster way?
2. Can the filtering(in the `get_new` function) be modified or made more efficient compared to using conditional boolean variables, as I currently have?
3. Can I in some way use numpy here for some speedup?

Edit: `df.sample()` is also quite slow and I cannot use `.iloc` or `.loc` since I am further modifying the sample and do not wish for this to affect the original dataframe.

Comment: what about [dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) ?

Comment: @Pierluigi - I am hopeful that there is already a better(and efficient) way to do this in Pandas or Numpy, before looking at other libraries. But thanks for pointing this out. Will certainly have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47149876/6361531

Comment: I created *tabel*, as a simplified version of pandas. It's entirely based on numpy but abstracts away the details of dealing with multiple datatypes. and numpy is usually faster in get/set scenarios like yours. https://pypi.org/project/tabel/

Answer (score 1):

I see a reasonable performance improvement by using `.loc` rather than chained indexing:

```
import random, pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[4,5,19],[1,2,0],[2,5,9],[8,2,5]], columns=['a','b','c'])

df = pd.concat([df]*1000000)

x = df.sample(n=2)

def get_new(row):
    a, b, c = row
    return random.choice(df[(df['a'] != a) & (df['b'] == b) & (df['c'] != c)]['c'].values)

def get_new2(row):
    a, b, c = row
    return random.choice(df.loc[(df['a'] != a) & (df['b'] == b) & (df['c'] != c), 'c'].values)


%timeit x.apply(lambda row: get_new(row), axis=1)   # 159ms
%timeit x.apply(lambda row: get_new2(row), axis=1)  # 119ms
```

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately no improvement in my case. It still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: @swathis. That's interesting. Can you copy-paste my code and confirm whether or not this has to do with your data being different to mine?

Comment: Your code block works. Using .loc gives me too a speedup for ~50 ms. 
Could my issue be because I am doing the indexing multiple times within the function based on some other conditions? Also, df.sample is really slow for me.

Comment: @swathis, yes maybe this isn't even the bottleneck. What I would recommend is split your code into many small functions and run your code through a profiler to pinpoint the cause of the performance drop. You can use `cProfile.run` to do the profiling and it gives output by function.

Comment: Using cProfile was useful. There was even an addon for PyCharm which made it easier. Thanks :-)